# Find object by key/value in an array in postgresql jsonb column

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE api_data (
    id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    content JSONB NOT NULL
);
```

Now I insert an array like this into the content column:

```
[{ "id": 44, "name": "address One", "petId": 1234 },
 { "id": 45, "name": "address One", "petId": 1234 },
 { "id": 46, "name": "address One", "petId": 1111 }]
```

What I want next is to get exactly the objects that have the "petId" set to a given value.

I figured I could do

```
select val 
from api_data 
WHERE content @> '[{"petId":1234}]'
```

But that returns the whole array.

Another thing I found is this query:

```
select val 
from api_data 
   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(content) obj(val) ON obj.val->>'petId' = '1234' 
WHERE content @> '[{"petId":1234}]'
```

Which returns the object I am looking for, but three times which matches the number of elements in the array.

What I actually need is a result like this:

```
[{ "id": 44, "name": "address One", "petId": 1234 },
 { "id": 45, "name": "address One", "petId": 1234 }]
```

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Right now 9.6, but I guess upgrading would not be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Postgres 12, you can use a JSON path expression:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(content, '$[*] ? (@.petId == 1234)') as content
from api_data
where content @> '[{"petId":1234}]';
```

If you are using an older version, you need to unnest and aggregate manually:

```
select (select jsonb_agg(e)
        from jsonb_array_elements(d.content) as t(e)
        where t.e @> '{"petId":1234}') as content
from api_data d
where d.content @> '[{"petId":1234}]'
```